# Deleting specific special string from file in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, sed

I have data of the following form:

```
<_:header16125770191335188966549>       <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#date>      "Mon23Apr201213:49:27GMT"^^<>   <4> .
```

I want to delete the string ^^<> from my file. Such that the resulting file becomes:

```
<_:header16125770191335188966549>       <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#date>      "Mon23Apr201213:49:27GMT"   <4> .
```

I tried to do the same using sed:

```
  sed 's/^^<>//g' fileName
```

However, I found that the characters still exist in file. Is there some way by which I may remove these characters from my file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` in a regex means the beginning of the line/string. You have to escape them to match literal `^`s:

```
sed 's/\^\^<>//g' fileName
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `^` is a special character in a regular expression, which in this context means "the start of the line". You need to escape it to use it literally:

```
sed 's/\^\^<>//g' fileName
```